# Elasticsearch how to query a multi-valued field with "shorter is better" scoring?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a multi-valued field `favSports` (not analyzed) in my elasticsearch index:

```
{"name":"Mike","favSports":["soccer","tennis"],...}
{"name":"Joe","favSports":["soccer","tennis","basketball"],...}
```

I want to write a query that find persons who like both soccer and tennis, this is my query:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {   "term": {              "favSports": "soccer"            }       },
      {   "term": {              "favSports": "tennis"            }       }
    ],
    "must": { 
      "query_string": {
        .....(Other query criteria)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in the query above, the score of `"favSports":"soccer/tennis"` are same for Mike and Joe.

I want to write a query that Mike has a higher score than Joe because Mike is exact match `soccer/tennis` while Joe have additional `basketball`, how can I write such query?

Another question: If I want "soccer" and "tennis" only (if someone like a sport other than soccer and tennis, he won't be included in the query result) how to write the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a function query will do this.

```
"script_score": {
      "script": {
        "file": "countReciprocal",// 1/doc[field].values.size()
        "params": {
          "field": "favSports"
        }
      }
    }
```